# Имя главного героя в названии произведения

Tags: литература

Как вы думаете, нормально ли давать название произведению по имени главного героя? Раньше это было достаточно распространенным явлением, но мне кажется, что такое название совершенно не отражает смысл и ничего не говорит о книге.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вряд ли можно дать однозначный ответ на этот вопрос не читая самой книги. С одной стороны, если произведение в составе серии, то имя главного персонажа делает эту серию узнаваемой "Гарри Потер и...".

Также вполне броско смотрятся имена с богатым ассоциативным рядом, например пелевинское произведение "Чапаев и Пустота" или его же рассказ "Затворник и Шестипалый". Но в тоже время только имя, без ассоциаций к нему, вряд ли заставит читателя заинтересоваться книгой, и взять её с магазинной полки, так что, всё это сугубо индивидуально.

Answer (score 1):

Нормально, и даже талантливо. И раньше было не так уж распространено. Вот в классике, например, много назовёте? "Рудин" и «Клара Милич» , "Ася" Тургенева, «Обломов» Гончарова, «Неточка Незванова» Достоевского, «Анна Каренина», «Отец Сергий» и «Хаджи-Мурат» Л. Толстого, «Саша» Некрасова, «Снегурочка» Островского."Бэла"Лермонтова. И все эти "заглавные" имена значимы, несут идею произведения.

Вот "Ася",например.Настоящее имя героини Анна, это брат её называл Ася.
Анна в переводе означает "грация, миловидность", а Анастасия - рожденная заново. Почему же автор миловидную, грациозную Анну упорно величает Асей? У Тургенева название произведения всегда значимо. Ася как будто освещает все вокруг, с ней мир оживает, главный герой становится счастливее

Comment: Как же мимо Пушкина вы пробежались)))

Comment: Не хотелось говорить о том, что и без меня "на устах".О смысле заглавия романа "Е.Онегин", наверно, учитель "уши прожужжал", должно и так остаться в памяти.

Comment: Вадим, Граф Нулин, Езерский, Анджело, Руслан и Людмила, Борис Годунов, Моцарт и Сальери, Рославлев, Дубровский... До Пушкина тоже есть известные примеры. Хорошая была мода, мне она нравится.

Comment: Только не стоит забывать что во времена Пушкина

 1. Писали книг намного меньше, чем сейчас.  
 2. Имя само по себе зачастую указывало на сословие, т. е. читатель мог предугадать о ком произведение. Современные же имена, за редким исключением, ни о чём о владельце не говорят, поэтому и используют их в качестве заголовка, значительно реже.

Comment: Волшебное слово - Фандорин!

Comment: @grumant, так Фандорины, фон Дорны и пр. ни разу не включались в название произведения. Началось всё конечно с имени личного, "Азазель", но это имя далеко не Василий или Александр и в говорящие вписывается, впрочем как и сам Эраст Петрович.